# Why is this auto-layout not working for iOS custom keyboard?

Tags: ios, keyboard, custom-keyboard

I am trying to build a custom keyboard. I have created a custom xib that my code is loading in `viewDidLoad` right after `super.viewDidLoad()`, the landscape views are not loading correctly on both my iPhone 6 and my simulators (they are scaled to about 1/2 of what they should be)

`// Perform custom UI setup here
let nib = UINib(nibName: "KeyboardView", bundle: nil)
let objects = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)
view = objects[0] as! UIView;`

[I have created a background view, and embedded two row views into that. I have set the constraints for the two rows to the background. Both rows have a background color of Blue so you can see them. Note the rotation screenshots and how small the views become in landscape.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vorja.png)

Really stuck here have been trying different things. At times the bottom row of the xib gets forced out of the view in Landscape, but this time I am able to get the bottom row to stick, but the landscape views are not scaling correctly to fill the keyboard frame like they are in portrait.

I am on Xcode 6.4 testing on an iPhone 6 iOS 8.4

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this myself by completing all rows in the xib, and redoing the constraints. all 4 views scale equally when rotating to landscape. it seems that without filling out the whole view with the 4 views (when there is only two) , when rotating into landscape mode, the view was compressing the height of the 2 views at a scale that was greater than 1:1